# What's the best way to show custom post types? With page template it's not perfect!

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, query-posts

I created a custom post type with name career. I would like to know what's the best way to list the posts. I created a page template with a query inside, but the pager is invisible. I don't know what's wrong.

```
<table id="career">
            <tr>
                <td>Position</td>
                <td>Location</td>
                <td>Close date</td>
                <td>View details</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        <?php $mypost = array( 'post_type' => 'career', );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $mypost ); ?>
        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
        <?php 
            $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
            $location = $custom["location"][0];
            $close_date = $custom["close_date"][0];
        ?>
        <tr id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <td><?php the_title(); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $location; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $close_date; ?></td>
            <td><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Details">> Details</a></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endwhile;  ?>
        <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older'); ?></div>
        <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer<span class= "meta-nav">&rarr;</span>' ); ?></div>
        </table>
```

How do you list your custom post types with pager?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [Template Hierarchy Codex entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

- To display the archive index page for a custom post type, use template file [`archive-{posttype}.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Post_Types_display).
- To display a single post page for a custom post type, use template file [`single-{posttype}.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Single_Post_display).

For your pagination issues with a custom query loop, [look for related questions on the site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=custom%20loop%20pagination).

Comment: What do you think about creating page template instead of archive-...php? I prefer that because my client can edit the content above the career, and he can use any url/title. Or this method is not recommended?